# How to get vueify running with Sails JS and Browserify?

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, vue.js, browserify

I'd like to create a SPA (Single Page Application) with `Sails JS` (Node JS Framework) and `Vue JS`. Vue JS supports components and I would like to dynamically load them (.vue files). Vue JS recommends to use `Browserify` for that, which I installed through `npm`. Tasks are done with `Grunt` inside Sails JS.

I just cant get it all together. That's my current public tree generated by Grunt:

`|-.tmp
   |-browserify
     |-components
     |--user.vue
     |-js
     |---dependencies
     |---vendor
     |-styles
     |---fonts
     |---vendor`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you do not fully understand how VueJS and SailsJS work.

I would suggest the way which I am working and many other people do.
SailsJS does not need Browserify at all. You could consider it if you would be using only small VueJS components, but it would still not be necessary.
Sails serving you an API.
Browserify is needed only for your VueJS project. VueJS is to consume your API.

My suggestion is to totally split backend and frontend projects and work on them separately in IDE.  In dev env set up proxy for your `/api` requests to point `localhost:1337`.
On the end, you will build VueJS project and put it in your Sails app assets. That's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for digging into this! I updated my folder tree to complete my problem. The folder is automatically generated by a Grunt task. So it is actually inside my Sails Js project already. My problem was or is that .vue has to be compiled and I thought that I can use Grunt to automatically do that (like the Sails Js built in JST to JS compiler).

Your solution sounds interesting. Could you provide some more information or links to read about this approach? If I understand it correct, the entrance point is the Vue JS index.html and it requests data from Sails JS.

Comment: Google Webpack Vue Template and go from there. It will be easier than you think.